# Ignoring or resetting datetime seconds and microseconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

When i preform `datetime.now()` to get the current time, it gets printed (with `print`) like this:

> 2018-06-14 13:21:02.331933

I want to ignore seconds and microseconds and to have it printed out like this:

> 2018-06-14 13:21:00

I know that I can convert to a string of my choosing with `strftime` but i'm not looking to alter the string but to change the `datetime` object itself so that it has 0 seconds and 0 milliseconds (and it seems stupid to do `strftime` and immediately `strptime` to convert back).

In other words to convert from `datetime(2018, 6, 14, 14, 7, 27, 326853)` to `datetime(2018, 6, 14, 14, 7)`

I've tried like this:

```
now = datetime.now()
now = now - timedelta(seconds=now.second, microseconds=now.microsecond)
```

And that works, but i'm sure there's a simpler and more efficient way (I need to do this thousands of times when iterating through different files). So my question is if i'm right that there is a simpler way and if so what are your solutions to such a problem?

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`datetime.replace()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to create a new instance, with specific attributes set to your desired value:

```
now = datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 14, 12, 16, 4, 738362)
>>> datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 14, 12, 16)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `datetime.replace`:

```
now = datetime.now().replace(second=0, microsecond=0)
```